# ios : MPMoviePlayerViewController all orientation support for the entire portrait app

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios6, mpmovieplayercontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

Entire app is supports only portrait orientation, only playing a video needs to support all the orientations.
The application is running perfectly on iOS < 6.0 in entirely portrait mode, now as the requirement need to support auto-rotation orientation for the `MPMoviePlayerViewController` (video to play) for iOS 6.0 as well, I've searched many things around, and I got below solutions so I've applied those in my app,

1) Support all the orientations in plist or in targets

[image]

2) add the below orientation functions for portrait support

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

3) Override MPMoviePlayerViewController class, and added all suitable orientation methods to support.

4) Put below method in AppDelegate file, and return landscape if you find an object of `MPMoviePlayerViewController`.

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window { }
```

but at last, there's no success! - I can't play video in landscape mode, only portrait is supporting in entire app.

I don't know why its not rotating? Is there something that I'm missing to set?

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to do the opposite in an app I developed, where I had to force video-playback to appear only in landscape mode. What I did was to let my app support all orientations, and instead override my mpMoviePlayerViews `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` method to return YES only for landscape.

Since you want to do the opposite, how about allowing both potrait and landscape for your app - but limiting your regular views to only potrait? (and thus avoiding your problems to allow rotation for your mpmovieplayerview) I think it should be possible to create a parent (view) class that your regular views could inherit from, and in your parent class just override `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` to only support/return YES for potrait mode.